# Asp.Net TextMode="Pssword" not save in database by LINQ

Tags: asp.net

```
 <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="col-lg-3">
          <label>Password</label>
        </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
<asp:TextBox ID="pass" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
           </div>
     </div>
```

I create a registration form and my password textbox is TextMode="Password" and when I save data in a database it shows blank in Password columns. my database connectivity is LINQ. here is a code of the database

```
DataClassesDataContext d = new DataClassesDataContext();
        Product p = new Product();
        p.Name = txtname.Text;
        p.Price = double.Parse(txtprice.Text);
        p.Size = int.Parse(txtsize.Text);
        p.Password = pass.Text;
```

and the screenshot of the database is

[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHxNX.png)

please suggest me solution for this problem. I am new in asp.net.

Comment: not related to the issue but dont save an un-hashed password in the database

Comment: you are showing dbo.reg and your code show product, same thing?

Comment: the screenshot is just an example of another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not using TextMode="Password".

In the Page_Load event, use:

```
pass.Attributes["type"] = "password"
```

or just put this in the control:

```
type='password'
```

This will tell the browser to treat it as a password, but asp.net will read it as text and store in database. However, I'd recommend against this as the built-in user creation and login controls have all the good security bells and whistles that you'll be missing out on.